# How to convert a polygon into line segment

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have a polygon which should be converted to a line segment. How can this be achieved?

I have tried the following code, but it didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
selectedPointGeom = interactionselect.getFeatures().getArray();
polygeom = selectedPointGeom[0].getGeometry().getCoordinates();
if(polygeom != undefined) {
    lineCoords = polygeom[0].slice(0, -1);
    let exploded_polygon = new ol.Feature({
                             geometry: new ol.geom.LineString(lineCoords)
                           });
    lineLayer.getSource().addFeature(exploded_polygon);
}
```

Here I am getting the selectedPointGeom variable from the select interaction. When I select the polygon, it should be converted to a line segment and get added to the line layer.

Comment: The code works fine and I did a mistake of adding the layer to my map

Answer (score 0):

```
  selectedPointGeom = interactionselect.getFeatures().getArray();
  polygeom=selectedPointGeom[0].getGeometry().getCoordinates();
  if(polygeom!=undefined){
   lineCoords = polygeom[0].slice(0, -1);
   let exploded_polygon = new ol.Feature({    
            geometry: new ol.geom.LineString(lineCoords)
        }); 
  lineLayer.getSource().addFeature(exploded_polygon);
       }
   map.removeLayer(lineLayer);
   map.addLayer(lineLayer);
```

This works fine

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).